# Change Tabindex in JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

My jQGrid keeps a tabindex with 1 value! I wanna change it to -1 or remove it.
How can I do it?
thanks buddies.

Here is the source of my grid, when jQGrid renders it:

[image: src]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#list_allprices').attr('tabindex','-1');
```

Comment: did you wrote it inside pageload?

Answer (score 0):

Late but sure, here is my answer:

I couldn't find an option to specifically set the tabIndex through the jqgrid element but I was able to iterate over all the elements I was interested about to set them to ignore the tab (by setting the tabindex = -1).

I did the following:

```
function ignoreTabs(){
        $('.HeaderButton').each(function(i, obj) {
            obj.tabIndex = -1;
        });
}
```

In the example above I look for all the elments with class HeaderButton and set the value tabIndex = -1. For your example Amin Sh, you should replace '.HeaderButton' by '#list_allprices'.

Of course call the function ignoreTabs when your page is loading.

Hope it helps.